# How to direct all newly registered domains to default holding page

Tags: dns, cpanel, nameservers

When you register a domain with, let's say GoDaddy, and use their nameserver your domains points to a default holding page. 
I run my own nameserver and when I register new domains I point my domains to my own DNS.

How do I set up a holding page so that all newly registered domains point to a default holding page.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Tx

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is that you want to be able to purchase a domain, update it's nameservers to point to your DNS server and then have a default webpage "holding page" for them?

You can do this, but you will need to configure DNS. DNS servers, by default, do not give out answers that they do not know the answer to. There is a mechanism called dns hijacking, but it is very frowned upon. So lets assume that for every newly purchased domain you do configure DNS. To create the "holding page" simply point your default records (domain, www.domain, etc). to a web server's ip address.

On the web server do not use virtual hosts. A virtual host will give a specific web folder to a request with a given host header. This means that if you request foo.com you will get the foo.com folder. If you request bar.com you will get bar.com folder, etc. If you do not configure your webserver for virtualhosts then the web server will simply return the default web folder.

Comment: I use cPanel on webserver.